# Convert Laravel Collection to an array non-recursively

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

I have an `Collection` of objects. I want to turn this to an `array` of objects. Unfortunately the `toArray` in `Collection` seems to apply recursively, and thus I actually get an array of arrays.

Here is an example showing the problem:

```
$users = User::get();
$result = $users->toArray();
dd($result);
```

In the above example, instead of getting an array of User models, you get an array of arrays.

It is clear why this issue occurs when you look at Laravel's source code:

```
// Illuminate\Support\Collection.php

public function toArray()
{
    return array_map(function ($value) {
        return $value instanceof Arrayable ? $value->toArray() : $value;
    }, $this->items);
}
```

Please note I still want `$users` to be a `Collection`, as the example is just a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I just don't want `toArray` to be applied recursively. Note that I am fully aware of bad workarounds such as re-hydrating my models.

Comment: would collect($collection->toArray()) be what you have in mind?

Comment: No because that returns a collection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$users = User::get();
$result = $users->all();
dd($result);
```

I think this is what you want. Give it a try.

Comment: `$users = User::all();` is much simpler, don't you think?

Comment: yes it does :) 
I just want to say use "all" instead of "toArray". There is no need for User::get(); Its same for this situation.

Comment: So, the answer to the actual question of how to "convert Laravel Collection to an array non-recursively" is to use `all()` instead of `toArray()`? I think the answer would have been better if you would have mentioned this, not just "fixed" the asker's code...